# Prevent Tomcat from interfering with Jersey/JAX-RS 2 Response Body on HTTP Error Status 4xx or 5xx

Tags: java, rest, tomcat7, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have the following stack for a REST API

- Jersey 2/JAX RS 2.0
- Tomcat 7.0.47
- Jackson 2

My goal is to have a custom response body when an error occurs. I want to be able to send the client an explanation what exactly went wrong for easier debugging.

First I tried to use `@Context HttpServletResponse` and set the http status code there, but it was ignored by jersey (which is the normal behaviour but this is beyond my understanding)

Then I tryed to use `WebApplicationException` like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/myapi")
public BaseResponse getSomething() {
   BaseResponse b = new BaseResponse();
   if(error) {
      b.setStatusDescription("reason for error");
      throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).entity(b).build());
   }
   //add content to BaseReponse
   return b
}
```

But Tomcat returns me somthing like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 - Error report</title>
        <style>
            <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22p
```

Which is the standard Tomcat html output capped by the contet-length of response body I wanted to return (`.entity(b)` - the length of `b`). So it is recognized but Tomcat just overwrites it with its own error page.

As a side note I also tried to just return the Response with the same outcome:

```
return Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).entity(b).build()
```

So how do I tell Tomcat to leave me alone and let my own responses through?

Comment: That Jersey calls `HttpServletResponse.sendError()`—and consequently invokes the servlet container's `error-page` mechanism—appears to violate section 3.3.3 of JAX-RS 2.0, which states that returning a `Response` "Results in an entity body mapped from the entity property of the `Response`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the GzipServlet from ehcache which seems to not work porperly with jersey. During the multiple phases the response wrapper threw exceptions.

This is the dependency of ehcache:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

And the problematic servlet definition in web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.GzipFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

As an alternative Im using Jetty Servlet now: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/GzipFilter.html

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0.RC5</version>
        </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
    <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,image/svg+xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

As disclaimer: yes I know I can activate gzip in tomcat config, but Im writing a testserver that must be able to have endpoints with and without gzip.

Answer (score 7):

Just add the following code in the configuration of ResourceConfig class.

```
property(ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, "true");
```

See [jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR)